# Time spent on jump instruction

Tags: performance, assembly

When profiling my code, I found that a significant percentage of time (~5%) was spent on a jump instruction; specifically `jnbe 0x1800...`. Unfortunately, I am unsure as to why a jump instruction would take so much time (a higher percentage of time than the `mulsd` commands immediately preceding it that are called the same number of times); it simply tells the processor to move to a specific location and doesn't actually do anything itself, right? My best guess is that branch prediction is failing for this particular conditional, which is causing this statement to take longer than I would expect.

Comment: Could be branch prediction, could be i-cache, could also be inaccuracy in the profile. Try profiling code including a long-latency poorly pipelined instruction (like `div %r64` on x86-64). You'll likely find the profile time mis-attributed to the instruction *after* the costly instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EOF's comment covers the main reasons.  CPU performance counters can track branch mispredicts, so you can see if that branch is poorly predicted.

Use Linux `perf` or Intel's Vtune, or whatever else you have available.

```
perf stat ./some-program  # a quick summary, not broken down by insn

perf record -e branch-misses ./some-program
perf report  # poke around at which instructions had branch misses
```